# data not getting displayed in asc order inside foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

i have an array stored in `$finalvendorid` that looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [vendorid] => 26
            [area] => N1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [vendorid] => 33
            [area] => N1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [vendorid] => 37
            [area] => N1
        )

)
```

from this i need to fetch vendorid and display its data. i tried to use foreach loop and then display data, i got the data correctly but i am not able to display it in ascending order (acc to avgrating)

demo view of vendor table is

```
id  vendorname  vendordesc  avgrating
26    V1            VD1        2            
33    V2            VD2        3            
37    V3            VD3        1
```

code for loop

```
<?php
foreach ($finalvendorid as $keyy => $valuee)
    {
        $newvendorid =  $valuee['vendorid'];        
        $sql01 = "SELECT * FROM vendor where id='".$newvendorid."' ORDER BY avgrating ASC";
        //echo $sql01;
        $result01 = mysqli_query($con, $sql01);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result01) > 0) 
            {
                while($row01 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result01)) 
                    {
                        //displaying of data 
                    }
            }
    }
?>
```

can anyone please tell how i can arrange the data in asc order so that i get o/p  of vendor in the following order

```
first vendor with id 37 should get displayed, 
then vendor with id 26 should get displayed and 
finally vendor with id 33 should get displayed
```

Comment: Provide table definitions and some sample data set ,also use one query instead of running in loop

Comment: @AK-Sonu but i need to filter acc to avgrating

Comment: @AK-Sonu   i need o/p in this order first vendor with id 37 should get displayed, then vendor with id 26 should get displayed and finally vendor with id 33 should get displayed, i have also updated my post

Comment: @roy You can use php sort functions to sort your array and display it wisely

Comment: @Narendra Sisodia i can use sort for ascending order, but i need sorting according to avgrating

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid i have provided a sample data and used varchar as table def, i tried using query outside loop but it didn't seem to work, can u plz how it can be done

Comment: You can use IN operator instead of single value

Comment: What you are doing now is executing 3 individual queries (one for each vendor ID in your array) and then display their data individually too.

The data that you retrieve from first vendor ID query have no relationship with the other data from the following queries. 

You have to store the data from all the queries into possibly an Array and then sort this array by the avgrating.

Comment: @Manos Forsaken can u plz tell me how to do so, coz i tried doing so but it didn't work out the way i wanted

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
ORDER BY avgrating DESC
```

with

```
ORDER BY avgrating
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    foreach ($finalvendorid as $keyy => $valuee)
    {
        $newvendorid =  $valuee['vendorid'];        
        $sql01 = "SELECT * FROM vendor where id='".$newvendorid."' ORDER BY   avgrating DESC";
        echo $sql01;
        $result01 = mysqli_query($con, $sql01);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result01) > 0) 
            {
                while($row01 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result01)) 
                    {
                        //displaying of data 
                    }
            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: still the data is not getting arranged in ascending order

Comment: Are you sure that you wants data sort by avgrating field?

Comment: Debug result after $result01 code by: echo '<pre>'; print_r($result01);

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will solve your problem:

```
<?php
$ids=array(); $v_ids=null;

/*get vendore id and store in ids array*/
foreach($finalvendorid as $key => $value){
    $ids[] = $value['vendorid'];
}

if(count($ids) > 0){
    /* make string of all vendore id seperated by comma */
    $v_id = implode(",",$ids);

    /*start your query here with order by clause */
    $sql01 = "SELECT * FROM vendor where id IN($v_id) ORDER BY avgrating ASC";
        //echo $sql01;
        $result01 = mysqli_query($con, $sql01);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result01) > 0) 
            {
                while($row01 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result01)) 
                    {
                        //displaying of data 
                    }
            }

}
?>
```